# how to maintain application state or some flag after firebase signInWithRedirect is called

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using reactjs+redux with firebase. I am calling a method signInWithRedirect for social providers authentication. Here after calling the method user is redirected to social auth page and then redirected back to my application. To get the authentication result firebase docs says that use getRedirectResult. I am using it but the problem is getRedirectResult gets called after few seconds and I would like to show some loader till it is called.
I am able to show loader by storing a flag in localstorage. Till here everything works fine, but when I close the window while user is redirecting to the social auth page the flag is set to true and when I open my application again instead of my login page I see loader, as there is no way for my application to know which state it is in, called from getRedirectResult or fresh load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`. It will only persist in the current window and will be cleared when the tab is closed.